# MoveIt!2 UR Driver: Parameter has invalid type

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have built ROS2 Galactic, Moveit2 and Main Branch of UR Driver https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver on Ubuntu. By starting like the tutorial from driver with MoveIt I got the following error on different parameters:

```
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1639652465.916282193] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00852234 seconds
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1639652465.917162913] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'ur'... 
[rviz2-3] [ERROR] [1639652465.936346953] [moveit_background_processing.background_processing]: Exception caught while processing action 'loadRobotModel': parameter 'robot_description_planning.joint_limits.shoulder_pan_joint.max_position' has invalid type: Wrong parameter type, parameter {robot_description_planning.joint_limits.shoulder_pan_joint.max_position} is of type {double}, setting it to {string} is not allowed.
```

It comes from a yaml File like this:

```
joint_limits:   shoulder_pan_joint:
    # acceleration limits are not publicly available
    has_acceleration_limits: false
    has_effort_limits: true
    has_position_limits: true
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_effort: 330.0
    max_position: !degrees  360.0
    max_velocity: !degrees  120.0
    min_position: !degrees -360.0
       shoulder_lift_joint:
    # acceleration limits are not publicly available
    has_acceleration_limits: false
    has_effort_limits: true
    has_position_limits: true
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_effort: 330.0
    max_position: !degrees  360.0
    max_velocity: !degrees  120.0
    min_position: !degrees -360.0   elbow_joint: [....]
```

And loaded in a Launch File:

```
[....] 
description_package = LaunchConfiguration("description_package") 
[....] 
joint_limit_params = PathJoinSubstitution(   [FindPackageShare(description_package), "config", ur_type, "joint_limits.yaml"]) 
[....] 
robot_description_content = Command(
       [ [....] " ",
           "joint_limit_params:=",
           joint_limit_params,
           " ",[....]   ]) 
robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content} 
[....] 
rviz_config_file = PathJoinSubstitution(    [FindPackageShare(moveit_config_package), "rviz", "view_robot2.rviz"] ) 
rviz_node = Node(    
    package="rviz2",
    condition=IfCondition(launch_rviz),
    executable="rviz2",
    name="rviz2_moveit",
    output="log",
    arguments=["-d", rviz_config_file],
    parameters=[
       robot_description,
       robot_description_semantic,
       ompl_planning_pipeline_config,
       robot_description_kinematics,
       robot_description_planning,
       octomap_config,
       octomap_updater_config,]
    ,)
[....]
```

Is there anything wrong with the Launch File, Ubuntu, MoveIt!2 or ROS2 configuration, that it tries to load it as string?

Perhaps it could have something to do with it:
I am not allowed now to publish a double with to_string to the RCLCPP Logger. It was absolutely working under Foxy on the same Machine.

> RCLCPP_INFO(LOGGER, std::to_string(q.x()));

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393090/moveit!2-ur-driver:-parameter-has-invalid-type/) by [FlorianSp](https://answers.ros.org/users/87787/floriansp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2021-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> it begins with "!degrees". I've never seen yaml files containing values that start with such string. Is that supported usage?

It has been supported in the past, for example http://wiki.ros.org/rosparam#YAML_Format

Possibly related: https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/issues/140

The current robot description for UR robots still uses this YAML tag, so I think it's been fixed since this question was posted:

https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Description/blob/ros2/config/ur5e/joint_limits.yaml#L18

---

Originally posted by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) with karma: 337 on 2023-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2023-06-27**:
Thanks, I've never known that format. Converted your comment as an answer and marked as an answer hoping OP agrees.